# Ceres make fails: "Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed"

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ceres-solver

I am trying to install Ceres on Ubuntu 16.04, following the [installation guide on ceres website](http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html), however when the `make` command fails, showing the following error:

```
[ 94%] Built target helloworld_numeric_diff
[ 94%] Built target helloworld_analytic_diff
[ 95%] Built target curve_fitting
[ 95%] Built target circle_fit
[ 95%] Building CXX object examples/CMakeFiles/nist.dir/nist.cc.o
g++-5: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
examples/CMakeFiles/nist.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'examples/CMakeFiles/nist.dir/nist.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/nist.dir/nist.cc.o] Error 4
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5885: recipe for target 'examples/CMakeFiles/nist.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/nist.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am fairly new to Linux, so any help understanding what has gone wrong would be very appreciated.

Comment: You're not going to fix an ICE on your own, in any case GCC 5 is getting on and you should probably install a more recent version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Killed” is what you usually see if something (external) sends SIGKILL to the compiler process. Either this is another user with permissions being bothered by this process or, more likely, the [Linux OOM Killer](https://www.memset.com/docs/additional-information/oom-killer/) evicting this process under memory pressure. I would suggest having a look at the memory consumption during compilation of “nist.cc”.